# Multiprocessing on pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, multithreading, dataframe, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am applying a function on a Dataframe column but I want to make it faster as the function takes a lot of processing time when done serially.

```
df[df['codes']=='None']['q'][:1].apply(lambda x: clf(x,candidate_labels))
```

Serially a single row just takes  `2.52 secs` for running but when running the code below using multiprocessing it's taking a lot longer `51.61 secs` and I have about `2500 rows` for processing so it is going to take a lot of time to run the function. I am looking to speed it up at least `20%`.

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def clf(x):
    ...
    return list
def _apply_df(args):
    df, func, kwargs = args
    return df.apply(func, **kwargs)

def apply_by_multiprocessing(df, func, **kwargs):
    workers = kwargs.pop('workers')
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workers)
    result = pool.map(_apply_df, [(d, func, kwargs)
            for d in np.array_split(df, workers)])
    pool.close()
    return pd.concat(list(result))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tart_time = time.time()
    res=apply_by_multiprocessing(df[df['codes']=='None']['q'][:1],clf, workers=4)  
    print(res)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    ## run by 4 processors
```

I have also tried different iterations for multiprocessing but none seem to speed up the flow instaed they slow down my code.

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
import time
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True)

start_time = time.time()
categories = df[df['codes']=='None']['q'][:10].parallel_apply(lambda x: clf(x,candidate_labels))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Another experiment:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def clf:
    ...
    return list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool(processes=8)
    pool_results = p.map(clf, df[df['codes']=='None']['q'][:1])
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: What is `clf` doing? Perhaps there are vectorized alternatives... also, multiprocess takes time to configure and it makes up for it on scale, but if there is no clear way to split the function into threads then you gain zero time and spend more time configuring the call

Comment: @RichieV Thank you for your response, so `clf` is actually running a pre-trained model for text classification which I am applying to every row of the Dataframe. Every row is a sentence that needs to be classified into certain topics.

Comment: Which model are you using? I know sklearn has multiprocess embedded as an option

Comment: Otherwise, is there a way to pass multiple lines to your model? I would look into that before creating multiprocess

Comment: @RichieV I am not using anything from sklearn. its a Zero-Shot Text classification model from HuggingFace. The function `clf` is simply doing 
`candidate_labels=['a','b',..]
cat=classifier(seq,candidate_labels)
return cat`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:
https://github.com/xieqihui/pandas-multiprocess

```
pip install pandas-multiprocess
```

```
from pandas_multiprocess import multi_process


args = {'workers': 4}
result = multi_process(func=clf, data=df, num_process=8, **args)
```

Comment: I just tried it and it takes about `17 secs` for a single row. Still slower than the `.apply` function and not at par with the multiprocessing results I was expecting.